# Prove or disprove a combinatoric conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, symmetric-groups

We have a vector $x\in\Bbb \{\pm1\}^{2n}$, such that its component sum $\sum x_i=0$, meaning exactly half of $x$'s components are $+1$ and the other half $-1$. We also have a "forward" operator $f\in S_{2n}$ such that $f$ sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$,...,$2n-1$ to $2n$ and eventually $2n$ back to $1$, thus forming a "loop". I conjecture that there must exist some $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $$f^k(x):=(x_{f^k(1)},\cdots,x_{f^k(2n)})=-(x_1,\cdots,x_{2n})=-x.$$
I experimented some cases for $2n=4,6,8$ and was thus led to this conjecture. I don't have further idea to formulate a proof/disproof, though.

Comment: (+,+,+,-,-,+,-,-)

Comment: can I call you.... Viminem?

Comment: @TheCount call me Svim Shady if you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjecture is false.  For convenience, we will work with binary strings instead of vectors in ${\{\pm 1\}}^{2n}$.  Now, if we index the elements of $x$ from zero instead of one, then $f(i) = i + 1 \bmod n$.  Let us say that two indexes $0 \leq i, j < n$ are adjacent if $f(i) = j$ or $f(j) = i$.  Then, for any $k$, it follows from the fact that $f^k(i) = i + k \bmod n$ that the indexes $i$ and $j$ are adjacent if and only if $f^k(i)$ and $f^k(j)$ are adjacent.

For a counter example, let $n = 6$ and consider the binary string $x = 010011$.  By the above argument, for any $k$, $f^k(x)$ preserves adjacent elements, so if $f^k(x) = 101100$, then we must have $f^k(4) = 2$.  This implies that $f^k(i) = i - 2 \bmod 6 = i + 4 \bmod 6$.  However, then $f^k(x) = 001101 \not= 101100$.

Comment: I see.. actually the conjecture is something i want to use to prove another result. Since it doesn't work I'll add the result I want to prove in my post to see if there's anything else I can do.

Comment: @Vim Perhaps that would be better as a separate question.  Otherwise, the question becomes something of a moving target.

Comment: ok, I'll make that part into a separate one.